# Where are all the legacy justice / honor vendors?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Since I've played only BC and MoP, I haven't been able to get nice-looking sets for transmogrification. Recently I discovered that there are more set vendors ("Legacy" Vendors) than the ones in Stormwind or Orgrimmar.

The known vendors I know are:

- Stormwind (Honor and Justice Vendors, Champion's Hall and SI:7)
- Tanaris (Honor Vendor, several PVP sets, up to Relentless)
- The Argent Tournament Grounds (Justice Vendor, only 1 set)
- Dalaran (Justice Vendors, some PVP sets for Justice, Tier Tokens, Heirlooms)
- Isle of Quel'danas (Honor and Justice Vendors, some PVP sets)

There must be other legacy vendors that can give you some sets for transmogging for either honor or justice. Do you know the location of the remaining ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are legacy JP vendors in Dalaran, Icecrown Citadel, Orgrimmar, and Stormwind.

Legacy arena gear is available in Tanaris and Dalaran. 
Honor Quartermasters are present in Orgrimmar, Tanaris, Stormwind, Valley of the Four Winds, Kun-Lai Summit, and Dalaran.

I believe this lists all quartermasters that sell gear for justice or Honor. There are other quartermasters, but all sell either tier gear (need tier tokens from raids) or rep gear (need to grind rep then purchase with gold/valor).

Hope this helps!

Sources:

- [All NPC vendors with "Legacy" in their name](http://www.wowhead.com/npcs?filter=na=legacy;ex=on;cr=29;crs=1;crv=0)
- [All NPCs with "Honor Quartermaster" in their name](http://www.wowhead.com/search?q=honor+quartermaster)

There is also [Kezzik the Striker](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=54650) out in Netherstorm that sells arena gear from seasons 1, 2, and 3.

Answer (score 0):

In all honesty I believe you have them covered. The only vendors I can even remember besides the justice and honor vendors in any of the old expansions, are the ones that require tokens, and those still require tokens to get. Ah, wait a sec, I do remember there being a PvP Legacy Honor vendor out in Netherstorm in BC, believe it was at Area-52.

Comment: I read that there was a vendor in the Netherstorm, in Area 52, but I couldn't find him. Perhaps he was removed in MoP?

Comment: No pretty sure he is still there, I don't remember his name but I'm positive he is still there, visited him on my way to Tempest Keep one time when searching for a lookalike shield to the legendary you use in the fight against Kael'thas Sunstrider. During MoP.